# customized error in C

Tags: c, header

I am fairly new to C.
What i meant by question is, i have several C files where i have my error print say

```
 if(sd_counter == 0)
     {
    kprintf("No directory exists!\n");
     }
```

in different file i have several same kind of messages displayed. what i need is to store these errors in maybe header file and call it on my c files as

```
 kprintf("%s/\n",err1);
 kprintf("%s/\n",err2);
```

so that i dont need to write whole sentence in each file.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i need to store those error in one place and call it on my c files. how can i do that

Comment: `#define KERROR_NO_DIRECTORY "No directory exists!\n"` maybe?

Comment: Use a *variable*. This should be covered by any C tutorial.

Comment: thanks guys. yes @rodrigo #define does what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by rodrigo
i have added #define in my header file to define different set of error

```
#define ERR1 "No directory exists!\n"
#define ERR2 "Duplicate name!\n"
#define SUCC1 "Successfully created!\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can store values in *variables* and refer to them by name.

Example:

**messages.h:**

```
extern const char msg1[];
extern const char msg2[];
```

**messages.c:**

```
#include "messages.h"

const char msg1[] = "Hello";
const char msg2[] = "World";
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "messages.h"

int main(void)
{
    puts(msg1);
    puts(msg2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kerrek for the answer. #define in header file as mentioned by rodrigo is what i needed :)

Comment: @Sanju: No, it's not, but suit yourself. (Macros are a very bad solution for almost all problems, and you end up *duplicating* the message for each use.)